# How to Implement shared preference concept in tabhost on android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost

I am self- learner to android,

Assume an android program  is going to display some result on a textview.can any one tell me how to show that answer on first tab of the tab host's on the next screen.How to achieve this?

As per my knowledge i googled and found "Shared preference" concept will be helpful to this problem. Was i right?

And i found some samples but they are not making me clear,can any one give me some examples with screen images.

Thanks for your precious time!.

Comment: " i need to show that answer on first tab of the tab host on the next page" !!. Can u kindly rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry my friend. I dont have any

Comment: okay...its alright.As per my knowledge i googled and found "Shared preference" concept will be helpful to the above problem. Was i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a small sample in this whatever you enter in first tab it is shown on second tab:

Main class

```
public class CheckkActivity extends TabActivity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override      
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Resources res = getResources();                 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NewActivity.class);


    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);



    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
}
```

NewActivity

```
     public class NewActivity extends Activity{
    EditText get;
    Button save;
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
        get=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.next);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


          save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(get.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewActivity.this);
                   Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
                   editor1.remove("answer");
                   editor1.commit();
                 sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewActivity.this);
                  Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                  Log.i("set value",""+get.getText().toString());
                  editor.putString("answer",get.getText().toString());
                  editor.commit();}
            }
        });

    }

   }
```

SecondActivity

```
      public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
TextView set;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    set=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.second);

}

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(SecondActivity.this);
String answer= sharedPreferences.getString("answer", "");
Log.v("get value",""+answer);
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
    set.setText("nothing to display");
}else{
set.setText(answer);
}
super.onResume();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Don't mistake me, please send me all xml files for my reference. can you?

Comment: when you click save in NewActivity (tab first)then value you entered in the edittext is saved in shared preferences.... then in next activity i.e. SecondActivity (tsb second)it is shown in a textview...

Answer (score 0):

you will have to save your answer in shared preference on your first tab just like this:

```
             SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
            sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("your_tag",your value);
            editor.commit();
```

Then in the next activity just fetch the values:

```
             SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
             sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(NextActivity.this);
    String answer= sharedPreferences.getString("your_tag", "");
```

Comment: Can you please send me some examples about tabhost using shared preference?

Answer (score 0):

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TabHost>
```

next.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

second.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```